# Completely Ignoring a Directory in node_modules

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, webpack, node-modules

I am getting the error:

```
./node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:2302:13 
TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'a' must be of type 'HTMLProps<HTMLAnchorElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>, HTMLAnchorElement>'.
```

I found out that this is because a package that I am currently using has @types/react as a dependency and thus installs that upon running "npm install". However, another part of the project makes reference to a modified (and thus not automatically installed) version of the same sort of file. This file cannot be deleted since it's referenced by other files.

Since there is a conflict between the two files and the dependency @types/react is **not** used or required, is there any way of telling my react project to completely IGNORE the @types/react directory? For example, it will still live and exist in the node_modules directory, but since it is ignored, the compiler won't complain about the repeated definitions? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Does `exclude` option not work for you?

Comment: For webpack? Doesn't exclude only exclude the resource from being read by the loader, not the entire project/webpack in general? Or am I thinking of something else?

Comment: Types are specific to TS. It's exclude in tsconfig.